# MacOS - /Library/Updates - Is it safe to delete or not?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-space

I don't have enough space on my MacBook (running on Catalina 10.15.7) and I found 6GB folder named Updates which is located in Library - my question is: Can I safely delete that folder ? I think that folder is filled by old updates from Catalina old version so.. I don't know if is it safe to delete everything which is in folder or not.[image: Updates folder]

Comment: 001-88090 is Catalina 2020-001 Security Update (19H114). Do you have that? (`software --history | grep Security` to check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no. I have people move other files to an external drive if they are not sure their backup is solid. If you have a solid backup, you can just delete files.

Once you have 10 GB free run the updates until you are clear of this.

```
sudo softwareupdate -aiR
```

Quit all apps before or right after you start this (except terminal app of course).